# How to reduce white space between row headers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the space between the different tables but not able to do so.

Comment: Not sure if I got this right, is this what you wanted to achieve? `thead td{line-height:10px;}`

Comment: No I want to reduce the white space between the different tables.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would seperate your css out into another file. Inline css can be very hard to find sometime.

To get all the tables next to each other, you need to change all of the inline css on `.row` elements to the following:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 20px; padding: 0 10px;">
```

I would also probably add `margin-top: 10px` depending on how much vertical space you want between each table.

Specifying margin-top, margin-left, and margin-right is the same as `margin: top, right, 0, left` if you want a shortcut.

Comment: But I dont want to reduce the white space of the sides. Its only the bottom space i want to get rid off

Comment: There is no element.style which parameter are you changing the name to?

Comment: element.style is the same as inline css. I reworded for you.

Answer (score -1):

Each table element seems to have the class `time` so you can just apply a negative margin to that class. Something like this should work:

```
.time {
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nJa45/4/

Now, that being said, if you are trying to eliminate the spacing all together, you might have better luck restructuring your table. Rather than having multiple tables, make the entire thing one nested table. This will provide a more consistent removal of white space.